# How to pre-fill a field with dashes?

Tags: custom-field

I need your help to create a field (phone) where the user would already see the dashes in the field without forcing him to write them.

example :
Phone: - - -

For the moment I only do this by creating a validation rule (REGEX) that forces him to write the dashes himself.

Comment: Have you checked "Define Default Field Values" https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_defining_default_values.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi @Swetha, yes this field has been created with "Define Default Field Values" -> field type "Phone"